# How to create file name with special language in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, ftp

I'm developing the app to transfer data by ftp protocol and I'm trying to create a .txt file with file name in Vietnamese language. I used FTPcf.dll but I can't send file with Vietnamese characters to ftp server. 
This is my code:

```
private void sendFileToServer()
{     
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File to upload " + this.localFilePath);
        if (File.Exists(this.localFilePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start upload ftp");                    
            FileStream localFile = File.OpenRead(this.localFilePath);
            this.m_ftp.SendFile(localFile, "ĐN_TESTING");
            localFile.Close();
            this.RenameCompletedFile(this.localFilePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Close!!!");
        }
    }
    catch (FTPException exception)
    {               
        Console.WriteLine("Send File Exception - Can't send file");
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

And the system have error: **the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect**

Comment: What is FTPcf.dll? Google doesn't turn up many results, and none seem relevant.

Comment: The original FTP protocol does not support Unicode. Both client AND server must support UTF-8 extensions in order for Unicode filenames to be used. Is that the case in this situation?

Comment: I tested with some libraries such as library of **limilabs**, it can send files with Vietnamese characters but my problem is this app run on Windows Embedded Compact 7. I tried using the **OPenNETCF FTP** library but it can't send files with Vietnamese texts.